# How to handle static QuickActions for iOS app using ViewControllers managed by a TabBarController in Xcode written in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, quickaction

I already created some (static) QuickActions in Info.plist for my iOS app created in Xcode and written in Swift.

I have problems with making them able to open a ViewController. Of cause, I already googled, but nothing worked for me. If this counts: I'm using ViewController managed by a TabBarController. Most tutorials seem to use NavigationController. But, I think it will be done with the segues, right? What code do I need to handle it?

Can anybody provide it please? Or does anybody know a simple manual/tutorial?

Regards, David.

P.S.:
I tried this code, but it seems to work only with NavigationController?!
Code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, performActionForShortcutItem shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: (Bool) -> Void)
{
    self.handleShortcutItem(shortcutItem)
    completionHandler(true)
}

func handleShortcutItem(shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem)
{
    switch shortcutItem.type {
    case "icons.quickaction.home":
        self.presentComposeViewController()
    default: break
    }
}

func presentComposeViewController()
{
    guard let navigationController = window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController else { return }

    let identifier = "MyViewController"
    let composeViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(identifier)

    navigationController.pushViewController(composeViewController, animated: false)
}
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean…`UITabBarController` has a `selectedIndex` property which shows one of its views.

Comment: And what code do I need to handle my QuickActions?

Comment: Is `composeViewController` part of the `UITabBarController`?

Comment: No, it isn't, I guess. I took this code from a sample project from GitHub and tried to get it work. Can you help me? What's my fault?

Comment: The view controller should probably be managed by something. You should have a navigation controller or a tab bar controller at the root. BTW, if you have the Github project I could look at that.

Comment: It isn't really GitHub, but…: I took project 60 from here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/asvszzv8lnje2f0/AABWtzKFRb1tRxRzlew9FWiia?dl=0 The ViewControllers are managed by NavigationController in this project. But unfortunately I cannot/don't want to use NavigationController. My ViewControllers are managed by a TabBarController. Can you help me in some way?

Comment: I still can't picture your layout…could you screenshot your storyboard or something?

Comment: Actually I'm not in front of the computer, so I cannot provide a screenshot. But, I'm using four UIViewControllers managed by a single UITabBarController.

Comment: So is `composeViewController` part of the tab bar controller? If so, you can just set the `selectedIndex`. If it's a subview, then set the correct index and then push it.

Comment: I don't even know what composeViewController is. I just copied it from the project from the internet.

Comment: I can provide more and more specific informations tomorrow.

Comment: Hey @ILikeTau, thank you for trying to help me. I uploaded my project here: http://www.filedropper.com/myapp

Can you please download and review it?

Comment: Your `composeViewController` is the third view controller in the `UITabBarController`. `guard let tabBarController = window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController else { return };

    tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2` should work (semicolon to break line). Don't forget to check for shortcuts while the app is launching.

Comment: Hey @ILikeTau thank you very much for your advice. That made it for me. You helped me very much. I'll post my working code as a new answer.

Comment: @ILikeTau, what code will I need for the first icon on the leftmost side? Just set the digit to 0? Because that doesn't work proper.

Comment: Okay, thank you. My other problem has nothing to do with your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution with the help from @[ILikeTau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5230900/iliketau).

I'm using the following code to open my ViewControllers managed by a TabBarController with QuickAction:

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
func application(application: UIApplication, performActionForShortcutItem shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: (Bool) -> Void) {

    if(shortcutItem.type == "app.quickaction.search"){
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = sb.instantiateInitialViewController()
        window?.rootViewController = vc
        guard let tabBarController = window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController else { return };
                tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2
    }
    else if(shortcutItem.type == "app.quickaction.home"){
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = sb.instantiateInitialViewController()
        window?.rootViewController = vc
        guard let tabBarController = window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController else { return };
        tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0
    }
}
```

This code works from both modes: app is in background mode and app is closed. I think this way is easier and shorter than the common way with multiple functions.