# PerformSegue from TabBarController to ViewController without hiding TabBar

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I created an iOS app with Xcode and Swift. My `Storyboard` contains five `ViewControllers` managed by a single `TabBarController`.

Is there a way to perform a segue from a `UITabBarController` to a `UIViewController` without the TabBar at the bottom disappears?

Comment: Normally that would be done by making the segue from a contained controller (in a navigation controller?) rather than the tab bar controller.  Any reason not to go that way?

Comment: It would be easier not to use NavigationController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

I was asking this question to handle QuickActions this way. Here's the working solution, without the TabBar disappears: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37710017/6423177

Answer (score 1):

The best way to implement this is to wrap your view controllers contained in the tab bar controller in a UINavigationController.  Then inside of that view, you can push the new view onto the Navigation Controller and preserve the Tab Bar controller.

Check out this link about combining view controllers https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/CombiningViewControllers.html

Comment: But that code don't work this way:     func application(application: UIApplication, performActionForShortcutItem shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: (Bool) -> Void) {
        if(shortcutItem.type == "icons.quickaction.home"){
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = sb.instantiateInitialViewController()
        window?.rootViewController = vc
        window?.rootViewController?.performSegueWithIdentifier("mysegue", sender: nil)
        }
    }

Comment: Do you know how to change the code above to use it with `TabBarController->NavigationController->ViewController`
?

Comment: You will have to rethink your view hierarchy.  If you have a segue setup between the tab bar controller and another view, it will not preserve the tab bar controller.

Comment: great answer - simple and leveraging the storyboard for the heavy lifting. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
UIWindow root
|
UITabbarController
|
|- UINavigationController - navigationStack
|                                         |- 1 - SomeViewController
|                                         |- ...
|                                         |- ...
|                                         |- N'th...SomeViewController
|- SomeViewController
|- SomeViewController
|- SomeViewController
```

This above is the **correct** view controller hierarchy. Trying to do it any other way doesn't make any sense.
In the example I only embedded the first set of controllers inside  a navigation controller. It will do what you asked for. You can use this embedding in any of the tab bar positions.

The TabBarController uses VC containment to show controllers. 
You can embed your controllers like this

[image]

Comment: Okay, I just did it like this. But why does my app always crash now when using QuickActions with this code:     `func application(application: UIApplication, performActionForShortcutItem shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: (Bool) -> Void) {
        if(shortcutItem.type == "quickaction.home"){
            let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = sb.instantiateInitialViewController()
            window?.rootViewController = vc
            window?.rootViewController?.performSegueWithIdentifier("newnew", sender: nil)
        } }`

Comment: Why are you setting the root view controller again inside the method? If you have a storyboard based app the this is already done via configuration.

Comment: I made this by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If the view controller you are segueing to is among the tab bar view controllers then all you need is:

`self.selectedIndex = INDEX_OF_VIEWCONTROLLER_IN_TABS`

That will move to the controller as though you tapped on a tab.

So, you can do `let tabVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController("TABIDENTIFIER") as! UITabBarController` (or CustomTabBarController)

then select the index `tabVC.selectedIndex = index`

Comment: Yes, the ViewController I'm segueing to is among the TabBarController: `TabBarController->ViewController`.

Comment: Then:
1. Instantiate the TabBarController from storyboard.
2. set the selectedIndex

When it displays it will show the view controller at that index

Answer (score 0):

If you're performing segue from `UITabBarController` to the `UIViewController`, you cannot keep the `TabBar` showing, although if you perform segue from on of the `view controller` (i.e. a tab) to the `UIViewController` the `TabBar` will not be hidden.